# Does $X$ denotes a random variable or is a notation for random variable?

Tags: probability-theory, notation, random-variables

In some places $X$ is mentioned as denoting a random variable and in some other places it is mentioned as a notation for random variable.

The meaning of **notation** is, it stands as a symbol for a mathematical object.

The meaning of **denote** is, it represents something.

If random variable is a mathematical object, then it must be a notation. Is random variable a mathematical object ?

Comment: The answer to the question in the title is "yes". Saying something "denotes" something means the same thing as saying something "is notation for" something. As for the question in the body, I'm not sure I can parse it. Questions beginning with "if" require a "then" complement, set of by a comma, not a question mark. Regardless, you seem to be asking a different question in the body than in the title.

Comment: @NoName Edited to clarify the question. Thanks for pointing out. That was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

  The popularization of the use of symbol x (as well as y and z) comes from René Descartes. The generally accepted view states that the use of x by Descartes specifically because of his landmark work La Géométrie (1637). Because of that work it ended up instituting the convention of:

lowercase letters at the beginning of the alphabet for known quantities (such as a, b, c);

letter at end of the alphabet for unknown quantities (such as x, y, z).

[Reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_algebra#The_symbol_x)

When it comes to mathematical object, the belief of their existence is commonly seen as the product of postulation. But I still think its an abstract concept, opened for interesting discussions.